# Shiny Dashboard Box Lines

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I have some boxes on my dashboard body. But the thing is, I want to make my Shiny looks like a white page with something to display instead of having some boxes separate them. I already use CSS to change my background as white colors, is it possible to change the box lines into white colors or invisible?

Also can I change my Valid statuses to white one as well? At the moment they only have

```
primary Blue (sometimes dark blue)

success Green

info Blue

warning Orange

danger Red
```

#### Pictures with two boxes:

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code that you have produced so far?

Comment: If you want "plain white" design then use something very basic like here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html. And I agree with jsb without the code it is rather difficult to say anything